# Compiler warning when using const boolean

Tags: c#

I stumbled on a surprising compiler warning using the following code:

```
private const bool DEFAULT_SETTING = false;
//...
string aString = (DEFAULT_SETTING) ? "1" : "0";
```

which generates the warning `warning CS0429: Unreachable expression code detected`.

After initially being puzzled, I realised the compiler is not wrong because the value of `DEFAULT_SETTING` is constant and cannot change. Therefore the `? "1"` part of the ternary operator can never be reached. But neither is the compiler completely right because myself or a future developer may want (or need) to change the default value without breaking the code.

Is there better way to use a default setting similar to the above context which does not generate the warning?

Note: You may want to know why I would want to convert `false` into `"0"`...it is to save to a settings XML file. When the file is missing, the software automatically generates a shiny new XML file with default settings.

Comment: You might consider using `#define SYMBOLNAME`. It will be left out of the binaries. This way you could create different builds.

Comment: What version of the compiler emits that warning for this input? I've tried 3 different versions and I don't see it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Is there better way to use a default setting similar to the above context which does not generate the warning?

Yes.

But first: stop using `SHOUTY_SNAKE_CASING` right now. It makes it look like you're a C programmer. C# uses camelCasing and PascalCasing.

Now to your question. If a named value can change then by definition it is not a *constant*. Use constants only for *things which never change*.  Pi is a constant.  The number of protons in an atom of gold is a constant. The name of your program is not a constant, whether this is the debug or retail build is not a constant, and so on. Those things change.

The compiler is within its rights to warn you about your code because it appears to be making a choice based on *something which never changes*, and therefore is likely a bug.

This isn't just a convention; the semantics of the C# language assume that a constant will not change *ever*. For example, if you have a public constant `Foo` in Foo.DLL, and it is consumed by code in Bar.EXE, recompiling Foo.DLL with a different value for `Foo` does **not** update the value of `Foo` automatically in Bar.EXE.  The C# compiler will assume that `Foo` will *never* change and makes a *copy* of its value in Bar.EXE.

To represent the concept "this thing doesn't change in my program, but it could change in a different instance of my program" use `readonly`:

```
private static readonly bool DefaultSetting = false;
...
string aString = DefaultSetting ? "1" : "0";
```

Comment: Thanks Eric, and also for the comment about `SHOUTY_CASING`...I actually do come from a C background as you guessed. Though I am quite used to it, camelCasing and PascalCasing are easier on the eyes and I'll start using that from now on in my C# coding.

Answer (score 4):

You can use compiler directive.
this line is the first line:

```
#define DEFAULT_SETTING
```

then remain as:

```
#if DEFAULT_SETTING
    string aString = "1";
#else
    string aString = "0";
#endif
```

if you comment the **#define DEFAULT_SETTING** the **string aString = "0";** line is active for compiling otherwise **string aString = "1";** is active.

Comment: Interesting idea. While this achieves the same goal, commenting something out and taking an active choice to change the value of a constant have different semantics, so I prefer Eric's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use an extension like this:

```
public static class BooleanExtensions {
   public static string ToOneOrZero(this bool value) {
      return value ? "1" : "0";
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
var val = DEFAULT_SETTING.ToOneOrZero();
```

You will not get a warning and it is *cleaner*-I think.